# usb detail via udev

Tags: bash, shell, udev

I have written a udev rule that call a script to send email when a usb drive is attached/removed. so far its working fine. but i want to know if there is any way i can include detail of usb drive in my email? how can i get it using udev? like usb size, label, mounted on, time. following is my udev rule and send email script:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/u/usb_added add %b"
```

usb_added script is:

```
sendEmail -f root@IP -t abc@live.com -s smtp.live.com:587 -m "USB Attached" -o username=xyz@live.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the way by using `udevadm monitor --environment`. This gives complete details when a USB device is attached or removed.